# Can Anyone tell me that how we can create the custom template for particular pages in drupal8?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I am beginner to Drupal-8, I don't know how to create custom template file for particular design for particular page.

For Example,

If I have created bellow pages in Drupal-8 and I want each of the page's custom template,

Like :

- Home
- About Us
- Services
- Contact Us

So for this how can I create custom template? Please anyone help me out to how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Heyo! 
So, Drupal page templating is managed through TWIG templates in your theme. You should first create a custom theme, which you can do following this guide:
https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming

Once you have a theme, you can create .twig files that will provide you with the means to control the html structure of the pages. Specific instructions are in this guide here:
https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/working-with-twig-templates

For example, creating a custom front page involves creating this file `page--front.html.twig` in your /templates folder. Different pages will require ovverides based on their name or node which is detailed in the above guide. However, it most likely is best practice to use a page.html.twig file to set a default style for the pages of your site and not have custom overrides for each node.

If you're new to twig, here's a link to twig tutorials. It's very simple and nice-and-easy to use!
https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/twig/basics

Answer (score -1):

Drupal Website Design is Theme Based. There are plenty of themes to install in the Drupal.org. Seeing the particular theming documentation you can know how to customise your design.

You can look into some theming tutorials available in youtube also.